# Angular 4/5 - How to make api calls using browser client and not the app hosting box

Tags: angular, angular5, angular4-httpclient

Is there a way an angular application can use user's browser client to make web api calls instead of relying on the box where the app is hosted make those calls?
Will it be a security issue?
How to make such app secure?

Comment: Angular uses JS browser API to make calls and does not rely on hosting in any way....

Comment: for some reason i'm getting gateway error on making calls to a box to which my host box doesn't have access. If I make the same call on my browser, I have 200OK response. App works complete fine when running it on localhost however after deploying i see gateway errors.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: <html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.9.11</center>
</body>
</html>
↵<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
↵<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
↵<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
↵<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
↵<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
↵<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
↵

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify: A website will always use the user's browser to make a request to a client. This can be confirmed by sniffing things like the request's IP address. Using another computer to make a http call for you would be high dangerous and would likely come into the catagory of Remote Access Tooling, a form of system hacking. Imagine if you could query a bank's website and make the bank think you were hitting it from an internal computer!

It is on these grounds that you are able to add security such as blacklisting IP addresses based on Geography, or altering content (such as Netflix UK vs Netflix US etc)

Regaring the error itself, generally speaking a gateway error occurs when there is a problem with the deployment. Things to check are:

- Is the application using a database, if so have the credentials been updated for the new database environment?
- Have any of the config files been changed in one environment but not in the new environment (for example environment.prod.ts -> environment.ts when you build for production)\
- Has the website started correctly on the server (such as IIS, Apache - whichever you are using)

Can you be more precise about the type of error you have received, 502 is what I'm assuming as it seems to be the most common.  Please provide some more information and I can try to offer more help.

Any questions, fire away.

Comment: app involves hitting cross environments. Response for some environments is 200 while others is 504 gateway timeout.
The host class has a nginx proxy. Would host permissions anyway interfere in app making requests from browser clients?